# Will doing this improve somewhat improve my site ranking (SEO)?

Tags: seo, images

So I like to post a lot on forums. And often times, I'll link images. I usually use imgur as the image provider. But this thought just came into my head. Would it be a good idea to have the image on a page of site, thereby increasing my site ranking (right now, I'm the only person who's ever been on my site hah). So basically, instead of linking [http://i.imgur.com/veCBW.p](https://i.imgur.com/veCBW.p) ng, I would link mysite.com/pagethatincludestheimage . And inside it would just contain img src of the image.

It would basically appear exactly the same.

Is this a decent idea? Is there any other way it may help my site? Btw, I also use amazon s3, so hotlinking will not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to do a while lot for you. Linking to an image only gives that image a potential boost in image search. It's not going to affect any of the pages on your site since it isn't linking to any of them (remember, search engines rank pages, not sites).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off putting the image on a page, then linking to the page. On that page, have links to the other areas of the site that you'd like to promote.

Note that most forums noref links, but your own page (the one with the image) of course will have non-noref links to the rest of your site.